# How to read an FPGA implementation report

Tags: fpga

for example:
Slice Logic Utilization: 
 Number of Slice Registers:               6  out of  18224     0%
 Number of Slice LUTs:                    8  out of   9112     0%
    Number used as Logic:                 8  out of   9112     0%

Slice Logic Distribution: 
 Number of LUT Flip Flop pairs used:     14
   Number with an unused Flip Flop:       8  out of     14    57%
   Number with an unused LUT:             6  out of     14    42%
   Number of fully used LUT-FF pairs:     0  out of     14     0%
   Number of unique control sets:         2

IO Utilization: 
 Number of IOs:                           8
 Number of bonded IOBs:                   8  out of    232     3%

Specific Feature Utilization:
 Number of BUFG/BUFGCTRLs:                1  out of     16     6%
what is the number meaning

Comment: Don't shout. The title is already highlighted, there's no necessity to write in in ALL CAPS.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with verilog and everything to do with an FPGA. The title and tags are wrong.

Comment: @nguthrie then submit an edit

Comment: @Mgetz, I didn't realize I had the ability to suggest edits. Definitely more helpful than my comment. Done!

Answer (score 1):

This is a report of how many resources are being used in your FPGA to implement your design. Read the documentation for this FPGA to understand exactly what these all mean. Basically this is telling you that you are using a very small portion of the chip right now so you should have no trouble implementing this.